# What is the reasoning behind only being able to tag one person in a comment?

Tags: support, comments

I am curious as to why we can only tag one user in a comment. I'm sure it helps with clarity and readability, but it seems a little strange still. What should I do if I wish to tag multiple people in the comments? It seems counter-productive to post more than one comment.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that the question/answer OP is always notified, so if you're tagging someone else there's always 2 people getting notified.

Comment: Afaik, the previous commenter is *also* notified, so it might be 3 people. Not sure though. Robotnik?

Comment: Related: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) (MSE)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've always presumed the rationale was to make it less-effective to use comments as an open, large-form discussion platform. Doing so is generally considered inappropriate (on most sites).

It also makes it harder to spam people via notifications (and also thus reduces the workload on the back end that is *processing* all of those notifications).

Comment: That explains it, thanks!